# IBM DB2 v9.7 HADR TSA failure on the standby server

Tags: replication, db2, hadr

I have an environment here where I have 2 servers running DB2.
One is the primary and the other one is standby. They replicate with HADR and failover is made automatically by TSA.

What's the default behaviour when the standby host fails ? Because for now failover is perfect when the primary peer fails. And then I can reintegrate the old primary peer as standby.
But when the standby peer fails, here is my problem, I have to start HADR manually on this peer. Is it normal ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved this with the IBM support.

This was due to the fact that our DB2 is installed in french language and that the script `/usr/sbin/rsct/sapolicies/db2/db2V97_start.ksh` is trying to grep "Database name" but on our system we have "Nom de la base de données".

So the script part going like this :

```
su - ${DB2INSTANCE?} -c "db2 list database directory" | grep "Database name" \
 | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]" | awk '{print $4}' > ${dbFN?}
```

has to be changed into this :

```
su - ${DB2INSTANCE?} -c "db2 list database directory" | grep "Nom de la base de donn" \
 | tr "[a-z]" "[A-Z]" | awk '{print $8}' > ${dbFN?}
```

I didn't write the end of the word données because it doesn't work. I guess it's a problem with the encoding on our server, fr_FR@euro.

This has been tested on both v9.7 fixpack 5 and 6.

And to answer my question, the "standby" node is reintegrated to the HADR cluster automatically if it's powered off and is powered on after that while the primary node has no issue.

Answer (score 2):

[Ember Crooks](http://db2commerce.com/) works with HADR and TSA a LOT on DB2. (She uses it for WebSphere Commerce, but you can apply the generalities from her posts.)

Here are two posts([#1](http://db2commerce.com/2011/04/04/hadr/) and [#2](http://db2commerce.com/2012/10/26/when-both-hadr-servers-are-rebooted-at-the-same-time-db2-wont-work/)) regarding HADR that feature a similar issue to what you are facing. Based off of what she has documented, what you are seeing appears to be normal behavior (or at least expected behavior, even if it isn't desirable).

Check out Ember's blog (the first link in my post). I subscribe to it as I've learned a lot of key things about DB2 operations-especially related to HADR and TSA-from her.

Comment: Thank you Chris. Funny that you mention Ember Crooks, because I've sent her a comment on the article about HADR failure (your link #2). I haven't got an answer yet but I guess she has a lot to do.
I think I'll subscribe to that blog like you recommend, it seems really interesting.

Comment: Sorry if I missed a comment back in November. I had some issues with my spam filter then, but have since fixed them. I normally respond to comments within a few hours - a few days at the most. On the standby, HADR only comes up automatically when the database is activated, so if there's a problem with your startup scripts activating the database. Any questions on my blog, you can always email me at ember dot crooks at gmail dot com. Just be sure not to try to reboot the primary node and bring it up while the standby is down - if the standby is down when the primary comes up, the primary does n